# Create customer using customer repositoryInterface magento2

Tags: magento2, customer, customer-account

I am creating customer with repositoryInterface

below is my code

```
 <?php
 namespace [Vendor]\[Module]\Model;
 use [Vendor]\[Module]\Api\CustomCharityInterface;
 use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
 use Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface;

class CreateCustomer implements CustomCharityInterface
{   
protected $_storeManager;
protected $customerRepository;
protected $accountManagement;
protected $customerFactory;
protected $addressFactory;
protected $customerInterfaceFactory;
protected $encryptInterface;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    AccountManagementInterface $accountManagement,
    \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customerFactory,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\AddressFactory $addressFactory,
    \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterfaceFactory $customerInterfaceFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\Encryption\EncryptorInterface $encryptInterface

) {
    $this->_objectManager = $objectManager;
    $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
    $this->accountManagement = $accountManagement;
    $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
    $this->customerFactory  = $customerFactory;
    $this->addressFactory  = $addressFactory;
    $this->customerInterfaceFactory  = $customerInterfaceFactory;
    $this->encryptorInterface  = $encryptInterface;
}


/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function createCustomer($params) {

    // Get Website ID
    $websiteId  = $this->_storeManager->getWebsite()->getWebsiteId();
    $customer = null;
     try{
        $customer = $this->customerInterfaceFactory->create();
        $customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId);

        $email = "test@gmail.com";
        $customer->setEmail($email);
        $customer->setFirstname('test');
        $customer->setLastname("test");
        $password = "1234567";
        $hashedPassword = $this->encryptorInterface->getHash($password, true);

        $customer->setCustomAttribute("position","Manager");

        $this->customerRepository->save($customer, $hashedPassword);

     }
     catch(\Exception $e)
     {
            print_r($e->getMessage());
     }

}
```

}

After using above code customer is not getting created, Please anyone help me in this code

Comment: its working fine to create customer. please check with reindexing

Comment: for me its not working, i can't see customer created with that  email, i checked in database also, its not creating

Comment: might be you have issue in implements CustomCharityInterface because i did use same code in controller using extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action it works fine

Comment: How it can be used here please?

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
$customer = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterfaceFactory')->create();
                $customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId);
$customer->setEmail($customeremail); 
$customer->setFirstname($firstname);
$customer->setLastname($lastname);
$customer->setData("position","Manager");
$objectManager->get('\Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface')->save($customer, $hashedPassword);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I have custom attribute for that , i am using repositoryInterface, how to use same code for custom attributes

Comment: with setData() it will mapped your value to your customer attribute. You can use it like this. I already did, and it works fine for me.

Comment: How can i create customer object? with custoemreRepositoryInterface? please update me that line

Comment: see my updated answer.

Comment: Same again, its not working for me

Comment: does it gives any error?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82762/discussion-between-jafar-pinjar-and-john).

Answer (score 1):

Changes the below code:

```
$customer->setCustomAttribute("position","Manager");
```

**to**

```
$extensionAttributes = $customer->getExtensionAttributes(); 
$extensionAttributes->setPosition('Manager');
$customer->setExtensionAttributes($extensionAttributes)
```

Comment: should take customer object with CustomerInterfaceFactory?

Comment: How to use save method? please update me clear code

Comment: I am getting below error after using this
Uncaught Error: Call to a member function setPosition() on null

Comment: `CustomerInterfaceFactory` no. I guess that you donot create extension_attribute.xml at etc folder

Comment: yes, i am not created any file like that.can you please update me full code, as per my request

Comment: you have to create  other wise any custom attribute does not save with api class /reposity class

Comment: How it can be done, can you please update me, i am looking for code, what should i write in that file

Comment: `/etc/extension_attribute.xml

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface">
        <attribute code="position" type="string" />
    </extension_attributes>
</config>`

Comment: I have multiple attributes, for all i need to add code in this file?